# I am getting WebDriverException and AccessDeniedException while using WebDriver; How to resolve it?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, access-denied

I am getting this Exception for every code I am running, so surely it must be related to WebDriver. How can I resolve this ?

This is my code:

```
public void TC01() { 
    KeyWord.createLogs("TestCases"); 
    KeyWord.openBrowser("Chrome"); Constants.logger.info("Browser is launched"); 
    KeyWord.openUrl("amazon.in"); Constants.logger.info("url is launched"); 
    KeyWord.windowMaximize(); Constants.logger.info("window is maximized"); 
    KeyWord.closeWindow(); Constants.logger.info("window is closed"); 
}
```

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: public void TC01() {
  KeyWord.createLogs("TestCases");
  KeyWord.openBrowser("Chrome");
  Constants.logger.info("Browser is launched");
  KeyWord.openUrl("https://www.amazon.in");
  Constants.logger.info("url is launched");
  KeyWord.windowMaximize();
  Constants.logger.info("window is maximized");
  KeyWord.closeWindow();
  Constants.logger.info("window is closed");

 }

Comment: I am designing keyword driver framework and KeyWord is a class in which I am writing all methods and they are public and static so that I can call them in my test cases as and when I need them.

Comment: Constants also is a class in which I am putting all my variables.

Comment: createLogs is one method , openBrowser is one method. openUrl is one method. closeWindow is one method

Comment: Just add your code to your post.That can make people who want to help more convenient.

Comment: I am getting this exception basically whenever I am trying to launch my browser be it firefox or chrome. And I have tried to use WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); and soemtimes System.setProperty(webdriver.chrome.driver, "driverexecutablepath");

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, sincere apologies. although the code is simple but its not readable without the other classes. But I am getting thie exception for every program now. Dont know if it is OS, webdriver or what ?

Comment: Sorry I can't solve your problem ,maybe you need to add more details to your post(not the comment).It will help.